# Gta 5- Director mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've completed all the missions for story mode in Grand Theft Auto V, and I want to use the feature called director mode. I've researched and tried everything, holding down the touch pad, dialing the 'Acting up' phone number (which results in just music), and I've looked for the Rockstar editing tab in the menu, which isn't there. I would really like to use this feature! Any help is greatly appreciated =)

Comment: What are you playing on? Xbox? PS4? PC?

Comment: IIRC it's launched from your phone in single player

Comment: I play it on xbox one

Answer (score 1):

[According to GTA Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Director_Mode):

> The mode is accessible from the Rockstar Editor menu and the Interaction Menu